# When is the bounty awarded?

Tags: support, bounty

My answer to a question with bounty was accepted, I suppose by the OP, but I did not get the bounty, not yet, anyway. Granted, the bounty was posted by a different person than the OP. I was under the impression that once the OP accepts the answer the bounty is automatically granted. But is the person who posted the bounty the one who has to award it ?

Comment: The bounty period is not over, and there’s an off-chance that your answer might be de-accepted.  Things will be settled at the end of the bounty period.

Comment: OK, I understand. In fact, I did not know one could de-accept an answer. So far I never wished to de-accept an answer I had previously accepted, but who knows when this could happen. Is there a place I can find how to do it ?

Comment: @Alfred I think you just click the checkmark again.

Comment: OK, thanks to both of you, ZeroTheHero ans JMac

Comment: Yes, it worked, I just clicked the chekmark to de-accept JMac's answer, then immediately clicked it a third time to re-accept it

Comment: Yeah the UI is pretty simple like that.  Most of the buttons work that way, even comment votes (though you get a warning when you try to retract those, because you cannot upvote the same comment again after you retract a vote).

Comment: Yes, I tried that and it worked  just as you said ! I'm learning a lot of useful things, tonight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Help Center Bounty page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> **How is a bounty awarded?**
>
> The bounty period lasts 7 days. Bounties must have a minimum duration of at least 1 day. After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty. Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer. (You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)
>
> **If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted).** If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.
>
> **If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.**

(emphasis mine)

So if no other answer appears with a higher score, you should receive the full bounty when the 7 day period ends (assuming your answer remains accepted).  You will only receive the bounty sooner if the person who posted the bounty manually awards your answer with the bounty before the period ends.